# "Condition is always true" when I know it's not

Tags: c++

I made a blackjack game for my C++ course. I have a problem checking who won the game. During the game I check after each draw whether or not that person busted (exceeded 21 in total). If they did bust I store it in a variable. They are `playerBust` and `dealerBust`. They are initialized to `0`.

The win-check is a standard if/else-if segment. It says that `playerBust == 1` is always false, and that `dealerBust == 0` is always true.

However, the last test of the game I logged both of these, and `dealerBust = 1` by the end.

A few explanations of my code:

`deck.newdeck` gives me a new, shuffled deck.

`initializeGame();` sets the player's and dealer's hand total to `0`.

`.toString()` simply return a string naming a card, for instance "Ace of Spades".

`getPlayerCardValue(...)`and `getDealerCardValue(...)` just evaluates the numerical value of the card just drawn.

```
void Blackjack::playGame(){
deck.newDeck();
initializeGame();
drawInitialCards();
bool playerBust = 0;
bool dealerBust = 0;
Card newCard;

// PLAYERS TURN
if (playerHand > 21){
    playerBust = 1;
}
else if (playerHand < 21){
    bool stopDraw = 0;
    while (stopDraw == 0){
        bool playerDraw = askPlayerDrawCard();
        if (playerDraw == 1){
            newCard = deck.drawCard();
            cout << endl << "You drew: " << newCard.toString() << endl;
            playerHand += getPlayerCardValue(newCard);
            cout << "Player's total: " << playerHand << endl;
            if (playerHand > 21){
                playerBust = 1;
                stopDraw = 1;
            }
        }
        else if (playerDraw == 0){
            stopDraw = 1;
        }
    }
}

// DEALERS TURN
dealerHand += getDealerCardValue(dealerFaceDown, dealerHand);
cout << "Dealer's face down card is: " << dealerFaceDown.toString() << endl
<< "Dealer's total: " << dealerHand << endl;

if (dealerHand > 21){
    dealerBust = 1;
}
else if (dealerHand < 21){
    while (dealerHand < 17){
        newCard = deck.drawCard();
        cout << endl << newCard.toString() << endl;
        dealerHand += getDealerCardValue(newCard, dealerHand);
        cout << "Dealer's hand totals: " << dealerHand << endl;
        if (dealerHand > 21){
            dealerBust = 1;
        }
    }
}

// WINNING CONDITIONS
if (playerBust == 1 || dealerBust == 1){
    cout << "Tie" << endl;
}
else if (playerBust == 1 || dealerBust == 0){
    cout << "Dealer wins" << endl;
}
else if (playerBust == 0 || dealerBust == 1){
    cout << "Player wins" << endl;
}
else if (playerBust == 0 || dealerBust == 0){
    if (playerHand > dealerHand){
        cout << "Player wins" << endl;
    }
}
cout << endl << "Player's bust: " << playerBust << endl << "Dealer's bust: " << dealerBust << endl;
```

Comment: Have you tried just saying `dealerBust = true;` and checking with `if (dealerBust)`?

Comment: @fuzzything44 Huh, no I haven't. That never occurred to me. Is it bad practice to use `0`and `1` for boolean variables?

Comment: @Auclair: `bool` is an actual data type in C++, and `true` and `false` are actual Boolean keywords.  You should be using them in C++ code. It is not recommended to use integers for boolean values and comparisons. That is what people do in C instead, because C does not have a native boolean data type. Things like `if (playerDraw == 1) { ... } else if (playerDraw == 0) { ... }` should be `if (playerDraw) { ... } else { ... }` in C++.

Comment: @RemyLebeau And even then it is a good idea to `#define true 1` to keep it constant.

Comment: Alright, thank you all. I'll immediately kill that habit.

Comment: @Ben, you should **never** `#define true 1` in C. This is just terribly wrong, and can lead to much headache. Instead, `#define false 0 #define true !false`.

Comment: @Auclair I rolled back your edit. The question needs to contain the original error, so that future readers will understand what the problem was and how the answers solved it.

Comment: @Barmar Yes of course, thank you.

Comment: @SergeyA Why is this wrong? what does `!0` evaluate to? because after the  pre-processor runs over this i suspect the result will be the same? http://ideone.com/r01AVS

Comment: @Ben _"Why is this wrong?"_ Because any value other than `0` will evaluate to `true`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Can you clarify that, in the online example i provided, i believe both interperations are exactly the same. It only matters once you cross into c++?

Comment: @SergeyA `1` and `!0` are identical, in C

Comment: Shouldn't `if (playerBust == 1 || dealerBust == 1)` be `if (playerBust == 1 && dealerBust == 1)`? It's a tie when *player AND dealer* bust. Your logic allows a tie if *either* player busts.

Comment: @M.M A supporter! I dont see the difference!

Comment: @SergeyA Since C99 you should not define those tokens at all, since they are defined by a standard header. If you don't want to use the standard versions then perhaps use `TRUE` and `FALSE` to avoid conflicting definitions when someone who is not 25 years in the past does try and compile your code.  (This is somewhat off-topic for a C++ question though!)

Comment: @kfsone Yes, that was the most embarrassing mistake. I fixed it though

Comment: @M.M if you do not have them, than !0 doesn't ave to be 1.

Comment: @SergeyA actually `!0` it does have to be `1` in all versions of C. Look up the definition of the `!` operator.

Comment: @SergeyA I added a question to cover this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565740/define-true-false-vs-define-true-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this:

```
if (playerBust == 1 || dealerBust == 1){
    cout << "Tie" << endl;
}
else if (playerBust == 1 || dealerBust == 0)
```

If the first branch is not taken then we know that `playerBust` is not true, and neither is `dealerBust`. So in the `else if` there's no point testing if `playerBust` is true (it can't be) or if `dealerBust` is false (it must be).

Answer (score 12):

You are using **logical or** (`||`) where you actually want to use **logical and** (`&&`) instead.