# CPP how is a boolean used in an unsigned int value?

Tags: java, c++, variable-assignment

I'm trying to understand this cpp code so I can convert it to Java. `r1` is an unsigned int *bit field* but it looks like here it is being set to a boolean value?

```
union GpioPins {
    struct {
      unsigned int ignoredPins1:2;
      unsigned int r1:1;
      unsigned int g1:1;
      unsigned int b1:1;
    } bits;
    uint32_t raw;
    GpioPins() : raw(0) {}
  };
```

then later on a loop containing

```
 GpioPins *bits = ...
 uint8_t red   = 141; // any number between 0..255
 uint8_t mask = 1 << i; // i is between 0..7 

 bits->bits.r1 = (red & mask) == mask;
```

The line that is confusing is the final one. Doesn't `(red & mask) == mask` resolve to `true` or `false`?

i.e. in Java this should look like:

```
 private static class GpioPins {

    static class Pins {
        int ignoredPins1;
        int r1;
        int g1;
        int b1; 
    }

    int raw = 0;
    Pins bits;
}
```

then later

```
GpioPins bits = ...
int red   = 141; // any number between 0..255
int mask = 1 << i; // i is between 0..7 

bits.bits.r1 = (red & mask) == mask;  // compile error, incompatible types
```

There is clearly something I don't understand in the cpp code, but don't know what it is to google it :-)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field

Comment: Do you understand how C++ integer truth works?

Comment: @chrylis By that you mean, 0 is false and every other number is true?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I understand it's a bit field, but i don't see how that effects the line in question? `r1 = (red & mask) == mask;`

Comment: It helps if you know that `!0 == 1`, see [also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565740/define-true-false-vs-define-true-1)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: That's not really true. `!0 == true`. Only when you coerce the result back into an integer do you see `1`. It's important to understand all the conversions taking place here, particularly when you realise that the bit representation of `true` need not be `0x1`; it only needs to be something different from `0x0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Doesn't `(red & mask) == mask` resolve to `true` or `false`?

Yes, it does!

Next, during the assignment to `r1`, your `true` or `false` is coerced into an `unsigned int`, with value `1` or `0` respectively. C++ has *implicit conversions* that make this happen.

Answer (score 3):

Assigning a `bool` to an `unsigned int` is a legal thing to do in C++. A `true` will set it to `1`, and a `false` will set it to `0`. This is done implicitly in C++.

In Java, the line: `bits.bits.r1 = (red & mask) == mask;` will not work because you cannot implicitly assign a boolean to an int.

Try this: `bits.bits.r1 = ((red & mask) == mask) ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: The standard states that the implicit conversion of a `bool` to an `int` will yield `1` (if it holds `true`) (see the [reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion)) - so it's not "usually" but always

Comment: Welcome, Tony. Seen a few of your answers today. Keep it up!